# systemd-networkd-wait-online.service causing Artful to take over 2 minutes to boot, but Apport says package is not installed

Tags: boot, apport

Symptons same on every release after 16.04.3.

At boot, system hangs on the Ubuntu screen with 4 flashing dots for over 2 minutes.

Ran `systemd blame` which indicated  `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` took 1 minute and 38 seconds to run and `NetworkManager-wait-online.service` took 10 seconds to run.

Ran `ubuntu-bug systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` which returns that the bug cannot be reported because it concerns a package that is not installed.

Without Apport working, I am unsure how to file the bug on Launchpad.

Comment: Doing an upgrade from Lts to  beta release could not result to a happy-end.

Comment: I'm just testing, so that I can notify of bugs.  16.04 was a bug filled release, rather 18.04 not be the same.

Comment: So you made a clean install of 17.10?

Answer (score 4):

Existing answers have suggested editing files in `/lib` in place or copying them to `/etc`. I recommend doing the following:

```
sudo systemctl edit --full systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
```

Then you can make modifications in the file, as described in the existing answers:

```
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online --timeout 1
```

This way systemd will take care of the files for you and it will survive upgrades. If you need to restore the default behavior you can delete the respective file in `/etc/systemd/system/`.

Answer (score 3):

Same problem here with Artful.

```
2min 52ms systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
```

As a workaround you can add a timeout for the service. To do that edit the file */lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service* and adjust the line that starts the service:

```
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online --timeout 1
```

Setting the timeout to 1 doesn't seem to have any implications as there's another service with the exact same task (NetworkManager-wait-online.service).

Comment: Why adding a timeout work? Also you are using artful, which is not specific to the version specified, which is xenial.

Comment: sorry for the delay of my answer... I did add a timeout since I do not want to wait 2 min on bootup.

Comment: Works like charm!

Comment: Btw. after I've performed a `apt-get dist-upgrade` the contents in */lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service* has been restored. The `--timeout 1` was gone. So this workaround is not update-safe.

Answer (score 1):

You can make `ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online --timeout 1` permanent by copying the modified `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` file from `/lib/systemd/system/` to `/etc/systemd/system/` directory, using the following command.

```
sudo cp /lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service /etc/systemd/system/
```

Comment: what is the unit of 1 in --timeout. Is it 1 second?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a directory `/etc/systemd/system/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service.d/`
and file `/etc/systemd/system/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service.d/override.conf`
with

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online --timeout 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Most people don't even need to wait for network to be up when booting. In this case you can simply disable the waiting:

- [What does NetworkManager-wait-online.service do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018576/what-does-networkmanager-wait-online-service-do/1018731#1018731)

The above link explains what the service does and tells you how to disable it, as most users without an IT department would want to do.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest solution I found:

> systemctl mask systemd-networkd-wait-online.service

Q.E.D.