# Fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 on a high end laptop has 2+ minutes boot time. How to solve?

Tags: boot, 18.04

I just formatted my whole hard disk and installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my Lenovo Legion Y520 (16 Gb of Ram, 7th generation i7-7700HQ processor). I read that the boot time shouldn't exceed 10-15 seconds. I'm still new to Linux, searching the problem told me to see where the gap is using `systemd-analyze blame`
, so here is the result:

```
     28.126s plymouth-quit-wait.service
     11.528s dev-mapper-ubuntu\x2d\x2dvg\x2droot.device
      8.639s lvm2-monitor.service
      7.561s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      5.723s systemd-udevd.service
      4.862s snapd.service
      4.697s fwupd.service
      4.387s plymouth-start.service
      4.211s ModemManager.service
      3.678s systemd-journal-flush.service
      3.608s udisks2.service
      3.029s accounts-daemon.service
```

The rest are under 2 seconds. Also running `dmesg` shows this (It shows around a hundred line, not sure if that is normal, so I'm only posting before and after the large gaps):

```
[    1.706449] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[    1.766858]  sda: sda1 sda2
[    1.767360] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    1.821574] usb 1-11: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0a2b
[    1.821576] usb 1-11: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    1.830362] psmouse serio1: elantech: assuming hardware version 4 (with firmware version 0x6d4f00)
[    1.846245] psmouse serio1: elantech: Synaptics capabilities query result 0x70, 0x15, 0x0c.
[    1.861928] psmouse serio1: elantech: Elan sample query result 02, 2d, a8
[    1.952059] input: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5
[    2.016532] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
[    2.780832] [drm] RC6 on
[   34.554607] random: crng init done
[   59.583351] EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

The results continue to reach for 570 seconds, but no way it took that long to boot. Not sure if I did something wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: You could plot the bootchart with `systemd-analyze plot > bootchart.svg`. That will give you a hint on what's holding everything up. I had a similar issue. For me it was the wait-online service (https://askubuntu.com/questions/949713/systemd-networkd-wait-online-service-causing-artful-to-take-over-2-minutes-to-bo).

Answer (score 0):

I also have a Lenovo Y520 and had issues with 18.04, but not always at boot time, my issues would happen when the system was put under a load.  Dmesg would report hung processes related to the intel video adapter.  I have since downgraded to 17.10 and have not had any issues.  I will create a 18.04 boot USB and give it another shot and provide exact errors and diags where possible.